# problems when I try to Display a tree of data using DomainService. How do I display parent/child tree?

Tags: c#, silverlight, linq-to-sql, .net-4.0, ria

I have a table called `MBAAlertTypes`. It's fields are:

> Id (identity int)
>   ParentId (int null allowed)
>   Name (text)

I have three rows in this table:

```
 0, NULL, "Parent"
 1, 0, "Child 1"
 2, 0, "Child 2"
 3, 0, "Child 3"
```

I want to display a TreeView with one node, "Parent" which expands into three nodes "Child 1-3". Here is the XAML code that I am using: pastebin.com   [--d0t]  gdU2frcn

Here is the DomainServices.cs class from my web service: pastebin  [dot]  com/j57yeeZK

Here is what I get on my Silverlight client:

[image]

How can I get it to display the TreeView normally using the correct structure as defined in the table? I am using LINQtoSQL and I have my one-to-many association set up in the DB editor. I'm using VS 2010.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: you could post your solution as an answer here :) Would be helpful to others with the same problem.

Comment: My relationship association was Id -> Id but I fixed it to ParentId -> Id... it was an error on my part.